# Do I need a sponsorship for a Canadian work permit as an EU citizen?

Tags: working-visas, canada

I am an EU citizen (under 25 years of age), with a Bachelor's and a Master's degree. I'm currently applying to Canadian positions, and often the application form has a question in the form "Do you now or in the future require sponsorship to obtain work authorization?".

I know that to apply for a work permit in Canada, I need a job offer. But do I need sponsorship? The role would be Software Engineer. I understand that the employer may have to file a LMIA (Labour Market Impact Assessment) request when hiring a foreign worker. Does that count as sponsorship?

I already determined that I do not qualify for Express Entry or other fast-track programs, so I would go for the regular "work permit" route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But do I need sponsorship?

Yes.

> I understand that the employer may have to file a LMIA (Labour Market Impact Assessment) request when hiring a foreign worker. Does that count as sponsorship?

Yes.